# Hash not changing the value

Tags: perl, hash

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $number = 1;
my %hash =
(
    key1    => $number,
    key2    => 'something'
);
for (1 .. 10)
{
    print $hash{key1}, "\n";
    $number++;
}
```

The number changes in every step. The expected result was `1, 2, 3, ..., 10` but the real result is `1, 1, 1, ..., 1`. Why the hash doesn't change??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign `1` to the variable `$number`, then assign the value of `$number` to the hash element with key `key1`. You then print that element ten times while incrementing the `$number` variable.

The changes you've made in "number" variable doesn't affect the hash since you have already assigned it and only change the value of `$number` afterwards

Unless you write your loop like this, and copy the value of `$number` into the hash every time it changes

```
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    $hash{key1} = $number;
    print $hash{key1}, "\n";
    ++$number;
}
```

Comment: alternatively, if you want any change of `$number` directly affect the hash you could use pointers like `key1    => \$number` and then do `print ${$hash{key1}}` to access it

Comment: @asp Thank you both for your time answering such basic question of mine. It took me some time to get through it but now I get it. I've learned that there are two different approaches - passing by value and by reference. I'm using now the reference to the `$number` variable and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a hash element is a scalar variable in its own right

What you have written is like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $number = 1;

my $hash_key1 = $number;
my $hash_key2 = 'something';

for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    print $hash_key1, "\n";
    ++$number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scalar reference to assign hash value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $number = 1;
my $hash_key1 = \$number;
my $hash_key2 = 'something';
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {
    print $$hash_key1 "\n";
    ++$number;                                                               
}
```

Derefering the hash_key.

Comment: `Can't use string ("1") as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use.`